# How to skip email selection and show only consent screen when the user already authorize with gmail and going to authorized calendar

Tags: google-oauth

I have an app with Gmail sync and Calendar sync. The user can sync one or both API for the first time.

Now if the user sync calendar at first time and after successfully authorization user click to sync Gmail then google show select email option if the user login with multiple Gmail account. I want to force to show only the consent screen. so the user can sync with the first email.